# SQLAlchemy: hybrid_property expression and subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to do a complex hybrid_property using SQLAlchemy: my model is

```
class Consultation(Table):
    patient_id = Column(Integer)
    patient = relationship('Patient', backref=backref('consultations', lazy='dynamic'))

class Exam(Table):
    consultation_id = Column(Integer)
    consultation = relationship('Consultation', backref=backref('exams', lazy='dynamic'))

class VitalSign(Table):
    exam_id = Column(Integer)
    exam = relationship('Exam', backref=backref('vital', lazy='dynamic'))
    vital_type = Column(String)
    value = Column(String)

class Patient(Table):
    patient_data = Column(String)

    @hybrid_property
    def last_consultation_validity(self):
        last_consultation = self.consultations.order_by(Consultation.created_at.desc()).first()
        if last_consultation:
            last_consultation_conclusions = last_consultation.exams.filter_by(exam_type='conclusions').first()
            if last_consultation_conclusions:
                last_consultation_validity = last_consultation_conclusions.vital_signs.filter_by(sign_type='validity_date').first()
                if last_consultation_validity:
                    return last_consultation_validity

        return None

    @last_consultation_validity.expression
    def last_consultation_validity(cls):
        subquery = select([Consultation.id.label('last_consultation_id')]).\
            where(Consultation.patient_id == cls.id).\
            order_by(Consultation.created_at.desc()).limit(1)
        j = join(VitalSign, Exam).join(Consultation)
        return select([VitalSign.value]).select_from(j).select_from(subquery).\
            where(and_(Consultation.id == subquery.c.last_consultation_id, VitalSign.sign_type == 'validity_date'))
```

As you can see my model is quite complicated.
Patients get Consultations. Exams and VitalSigns are cascading data for the Consultations. The idea is that all consultations do not get a validity but that new consultations make the previous consultations validity not interesting: I only want the validity from the last consultation; if a patient has a validity in previous consultations, I'm not interested.

What I would like to do is to be able to order by the hybrid_property last_consultation_validity.

The output SQL looks ok to me:

```
SELECT vital_sign.value 
FROM (SELECT consultation.id AS last_consultation_id 
FROM consultation, patient 
WHERE consultation.patient_id = patient.id ORDER BY consultation.created_at DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?), vital_sign JOIN exam ON exam.id = vital_sign.exam_id JOIN consultation ON consultation.id = exam.consultation_id 
WHERE consultation.id = last_consultation_id AND vital_sign.sign_type = ?
```

But when I order the patients by last_consultation_validity, the rows do not get ordered ... 
When I execute the same select outside of the hybrid_property, to retrieve the date for each patient (just setting the patient.id), I get the good values. Surprising is that the SQL is slightly different, removing `patient` in the `FROM`in the `SELECT`.

So I'm actually wondering if this is a bug in SQLAlchemy or if I'm doing something wrong ... Any help would be greatly appreciated.